# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to lock app orientation to landscape?

Tags: ipad, orientation, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building a mobile app for iPad using Worklight. I need to lock the screen orientation to landscape mode throughout my app.

I've set the following setting in the `config.xml` located at `ipad\native` folder but it still not locking it, i.e. the app still rotate when i change the simulator to portrait mode.

The setting i'd added:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

I'm using Worklight 6.0. Any comments or suggestion are welcome.

Comment: See my answer. Can this question be resolved?

Comment: Not yet as we're running into problem trying to compile it. The problem is describe here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014851055 I use the zipped file to export to XCode but it still gives me the same headache..

Comment: I understand, however that is not related to *this* question, which asks how to set orientation. If you have another problem, that would be a *new* question. So, if this question is resolved, please mark it as Answered.

Comment: I can't be certain that it is resolved as i haven't been able to test it out on the device due to the compilation issue. Don't worry, once i manage to get it compiled and tested on the device, i'll marked this as done. :)

Comment: Feel free to open a question about to compilation issue.

Comment: I'd open it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401671/worklight-xcode-5-compilation-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a Worklight-related setting, but an Xcode one.

In Xcode, select your project form the left pane and then choose the General tab. In it you will find a "Device orientation" section.

There you select the required orientations for your app:

[image]